# SecurityContextHolder import not working in spring boot application

Tags: spring-boot, spring-security, vaadin

I've added following dependencies in my project.

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-security-web</artifactId>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-security-config</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

trying to import following

```
import org.springframework.security.core.Authentication;
import org.springframework.security.core.context.SecurityContextHolder
```

other files like import org.springframework.security.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationToken are getting imported but unable to import above mentioned classes.

I've checked the jar these classes are available but eclipse doesn't show them while importing;

Comment: Any specific reason you are not using `spring-boot-starter-security` dependency ? Try `<artifactId>spring-security-core</artifactId>` otherwise

Answer (score 7):

Replace the spring security dependencies with the Spring-Boot starter maven dependency

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>          
    </dependency>
```